# Incosistent behavior with multiple Git push URLs

Tags: git

I have been successfully migrating development teams from one Git hosting service to another by using multiple push URLs. When the switchover finally happens we just change the origin.

I had a need to do basically this same thing in a pipeline. I need to push a change from one repository to another, because of a pipeline that can not be attached to our primary repo.

From my local machine I initialized the duplicate repo by adding it as a push URL and pushed the contents. That works fine. I then remove the additional push URL and push a change to just the primary repo.

In the pipeline the push URL for the duplicate repo is added, but when I go to push I get an error that the tip of the branch is behind the target repository. All of this happens in the same branch locally and in the pipeline. How can this be?

When I try adding the duplicate repo push URL back to my local config and push, the changes go up without a problem. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

The pipeline is in Azure DevOps and the duplicate repo is in AWS CodeCommit.

Comment: Hmm, I'd recommend using several remotes, each having a distinct URL. Then you have everything under control. I am using this setup for years without problems.

Comment: @AdrianW how is that different from multiple push URLs?

Comment: You can fetch and push from/to each remote separately

Answer (score 0):

As @adrianw indicated, using the Remote URLs seems to be more reliable than PushURLs. In my pipeline I just changed the adding of a PushURL to setting the Remote URL and it works.